The published robot description file (urdf) seems not to be genuine
I am modifying existing hardware interface ros2_control_diff_drive(example_2) for my actual(physical) diff_drive setup. I have been following this tutorial.
In the example_2 files, i have modified only "diffbot_system.cpp" and "diffbot_system.hpp". NOTE THAT I HAVE NOT MODIFIED ANY URDF FILES.
I am getting the following error:
ros2_control_node-1] [INFO] [1730118567.236983125] [controller_manager]: Received robot description from topic.
[ros2_control_node-1] [INFO] [1730118567.238006594] [resource_manager]: Loading hardware 'DiffBot' 
[ros2_control_node-1] [ERROR] [1730118567.241820288] [controller_manager]: The published robot description file (urdf) seems not to be genuine. The following error was caught:open: No such file or directory
[spawner-3] [INFO] [1730118569.794680257] [spawner_diffbot_base_controller]: Waiting for '/controller_manager' services to be available
[spawner-3] [ERROR] [1730118577.901102661] [spawner_diffbot_base_controller]: Controller manager not available

The modified files are:
1. diffbot_system.hpp
// Copyright 2021 ros2_control Development Team
//
// Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
// you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
// You may obtain a copy of the License at
//
//     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
//
// Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
// distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
// WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
// See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
// limitations under the License.

#ifndef ROS2_CONTROL_DEMO_EXAMPLE_2__DIFFBOT_SYSTEM_HPP_
#define ROS2_CONTROL_DEMO_EXAMPLE_2__DIFFBOT_SYSTEM_HPP_

#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

#include "hardware_interface/handle.hpp"
#include "hardware_interface/hardware_info.hpp"
#include "hardware_interface/system_interface.hpp"
#include "hardware_interface/types/hardware_interface_return_values.hpp"
#include "rclcpp/clock.hpp"
#include "rclcpp/duration.hpp"
#include "rclcpp/macros.hpp"
#include "rclcpp/time.hpp"
#include "rclcpp_lifecycle/node_interfaces/lifecycle_node_interface.hpp"
#include "rclcpp_lifecycle/state.hpp"

#include "ros2_control_demo_example_2/serial_comm.hpp"

namespace ros2_control_demo_example_2
{
class DiffBotSystemHardware : public hardware_interface::SystemInterface
{
public:
  RCLCPP_SHARED_PTR_DEFINITIONS(DiffBotSystemHardware);

  hardware_interface::CallbackReturn on_init(
    const hardware_interface::HardwareInfo & info) override;

  std::vector<hardware_interface::StateInterface> export_state_interfaces() override;

  std::vector<hardware_interface::CommandInterface> export_command_interfaces() override;

  hardware_interface::CallbackReturn on_activate(
    const rclcpp_lifecycle::State & previous_state) override;

  hardware_interface::CallbackReturn on_deactivate(
    const rclcpp_lifecycle::State & previous_state) override;

  hardware_interface::return_type read(
    const rclcpp::Time & time, const rclcpp::Duration & period) override;

  hardware_interface::return_type write(
    const rclcpp::Time & time, const rclcpp::Duration & period) override;

private:

  GlowLed led_1;

  // Store the command for the simulated robot
  std::vector<double> hw_commands_;
  std::vector<double> hw_positions_;
  std::vector<double> hw_velocities_;
};

}  // namespace ros2_control_demo_example_2

#endif  // ROS2_CONTROL_DEMO_EXAMPLE_2__DIFFBOT_SYSTEM_HPP_


2. diffbot_system.cpp
// Copyright 2021 ros2_control Development Team
//
// Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
// you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
// You may obtain a copy of the License at
//
//     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
//
// Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
// distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
// WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
// See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
// limitations under the License.

#include "ros2_control_demo_example_2/diffbot_system.hpp"

#include <chrono>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstddef>
#include <limits>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
//#include <string>

#include "hardware_interface/lexical_casts.hpp"
#include "hardware_interface/types/hardware_interface_type_values.hpp"
#include "rclcpp/rclcpp.hpp"

namespace ros2_control_demo_example_2
{
hardware_interface::CallbackReturn DiffBotSystemHardware::on_init(
  const hardware_interface::HardwareInfo & info)
{
  if (
    hardware_interface::SystemInterface::on_init(info) !=
    hardware_interface::CallbackReturn::SUCCESS)
  {
    return hardware_interface::CallbackReturn::ERROR;
  }

  hw_positions_.resize(info_.joints.size(), std::numeric_limits<double>::quiet_NaN());
  hw_velocities_.resize(info_.joints.size(), std::numeric_limits<double>::quiet_NaN());
  hw_commands_.resize(info_.joints.size(), std::numeric_limits<double>::quiet_NaN());

  for (const hardware_interface::ComponentInfo & joint : info_.joints)
  {
    // DiffBotSystem has exactly two states and one command interface on each joint
    if (joint.command_interfaces.size() != 1)
    {
      RCLCPP_FATAL(
        rclcpp::get_logger("DiffBotSystemHardware"),
        "Joint '%s' has %zu command interfaces found. 1 expected.", joint.name.c_str(),
        joint.command_interfaces.size());
      return hardware_interface::CallbackReturn::ERROR;
    }

    if (joint.command_interfaces[0].name != hardware_interface::HW_IF_VELOCITY)
    {
      RCLCPP_FATAL(
        rclcpp::get_logger("DiffBotSystemHardware"),
        "Joint '%s' have %s command interfaces found. '%s' expected.", joint.name.c_str(),
        joint.command_interfaces[0].name.c_str(), hardware_interface::HW_IF_VELOCITY);
      return hardware_interface::CallbackReturn::ERROR;
    }

    if (joint.state_interfaces.size() != 2)
    {
      RCLCPP_FATAL(
        rclcpp::get_logger("DiffBotSystemHardware"),
        "Joint '%s' has %zu state interface. 2 expected.", joint.name.c_str(),
        joint.state_interfaces.size());
      return hardware_interface::CallbackReturn::ERROR;
    }

    if (joint.state_interfaces[0].name != hardware_interface::HW_IF_POSITION)
    {
      RCLCPP_FATAL(
        rclcpp::get_logger("DiffBotSystemHardware"),
        "Joint '%s' have '%s' as first state interface. '%s' expected.", joint.name.c_str(),
        joint.state_interfaces[0].name.c_str(), hardware_interface::HW_IF_POSITION);
      return hardware_interface::CallbackReturn::ERROR;
    }

    if (joint.state_interfaces[1].name != hardware_interface::HW_IF_VELOCITY)
    {
      RCLCPP_FATAL(
        rclcpp::get_logger("DiffBotSystemHardware"),
        "Joint '%s' have '%s' as second state interface. '%s' expected.", joint.name.c_str(),
        joint.state_interfaces[1].name.c_str(), hardware_interface::HW_IF_VELOCITY);
      return hardware_interface::CallbackReturn::ERROR;
    }
  }

  return hardware_interface::CallbackReturn::SUCCESS;
}

std::vector<hardware_interface::StateInterface> DiffBotSystemHardware::export_state_interfaces()
{
  std::vector<hardware_interface::StateInterface> state_interfaces;
  for (auto i = 0u; i < info_.joints.size(); i++)
  {
    state_interfaces.emplace_back(hardware_interface::StateInterface(
      info_.joints[i].name, hardware_interface::HW_IF_POSITION, &hw_positions_[i]));
    state_interfaces.emplace_back(hardware_interface::StateInterface(
      info_.joints[i].name, hardware_interface::HW_IF_VELOCITY, &hw_velocities_[i]));
  }

  return state_interfaces;
}

std::vector<hardware_interface::CommandInterface> DiffBotSystemHardware::export_command_interfaces()
{
  std::vector<hardware_interface::CommandInterface> command_interfaces;
  for (auto i = 0u; i < info_.joints.size(); i++)
  {
    command_interfaces.emplace_back(hardware_interface::CommandInterface(
      info_.joints[i].name, hardware_interface::HW_IF_VELOCITY, &hw_commands_[i]));
  }

  return command_interfaces;
}

hardware_interface::CallbackReturn DiffBotSystemHardware::on_activate(
  const rclcpp_lifecycle::State & /*previous_state*/)
{
  RCLCPP_INFO(rclcpp::get_logger("DiffBotSystemHardware"), "Activating ...please wait...");

  // set some default values
  for (auto i = 0u; i < hw_positions_.size(); i++)
  {
    if (std::isnan(hw_positions_[i]))
    {
      hw_positions_[i] = 0;
      hw_velocities_[i] = 0;
      hw_commands_[i] = 0;
    }
  }

  return hardware_interface::CallbackReturn::SUCCESS;
}

hardware_interface::CallbackReturn DiffBotSystemHardware::on_deactivate(
  const rclcpp_lifecycle::State & /*previous_state*/)
{
  RCLCPP_INFO(rclcpp::get_logger("DiffBotSystemHardware"), "Deactivating...");  

  return hardware_interface::CallbackReturn::SUCCESS;
}

hardware_interface::return_type DiffBotSystemHardware::read(
  const rclcpp::Time & /*time*/, const rclcpp::Duration & period)
{
  RCLCPP_INFO(rclcpp::get_logger("DiffBotSystemHardware"), "Reading...");
  return hardware_interface::return_type::OK;
}

hardware_interface::return_type ros2_control_demo_example_2 ::DiffBotSystemHardware::write(
  const rclcpp::Time & /*time*/, const rclcpp::Duration & /*period*/)
{
  RCLCPP_INFO(rclcpp::get_logger("DiffBotSystemHardware"), "Writing: %.5f", hw_commands_[0]);

  // for (auto i = 0u; i < hw_commands_.size(); i++)

  led_1.send_data(std::to_string(hw_commands_[0]));

  return hardware_interface::return_type::OK;
}

}  // namespace ros2_control_demo_example_2

#include "pluginlib/class_list_macros.hpp"
PLUGINLIB_EXPORT_CLASS(
  ros2_control_demo_example_2::DiffBotSystemHardware, hardware_interface::SystemInterface)


Let me know if any other information is required.
Edit_1:
After further inspection, I found that an error occurs specifically when creating an object of the class GlowLed in the file diffbot_system.hpp, under the Private tag, using GlowLed led_1_;.
Below is the code for "serial_comm.hpp" containing definition of class "GlowLed".
3. serial_comm.hpp
#ifndef DIFFDRIVE_ARDUINO_ARDUINO_COMMS_HPP

#define DIFFDRIVE_ARDUINO_ARDUINO_COMMS_HPP
#include 
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include 
class GlowLed
{
public:
GlowLed():serial(io, port){
port = "/dev/ttyACM0";
baud_rate = 9600;
        serial.set_option(boost::asio::serial_port_base::baud_rate(baud_rate));
    } 

    void send_data(std::string data){

                // std::cout<<"Enter 1 to turn LED ON and 0 to turn LED OFF.";
            
                boost::asio::write(serial, boost::asio::buffer(data));
                
                //std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));

            
    }

private:
    std::string port;
    unsigned int baud_rate;
    boost::asio::io_service io;
    boost::asio::serial_port serial;
    // std::string data;

};
#endif
Thanks

have you used the correct branch (e.g., humble for humble distro?). Have you built and sourced the ros2_control_demo_description package? use colcon build --packages-up-to ros2_control_demo_example_2

I cloned  the demo repo locally and switched to Iron branch using git. Next i took only example_2 folder and discarded the rest of files/folders then build it using colcon build.
NOTE that before making any changes to "diffbot_system.cpp" and "diffbot_system.hpp" file, every thing was working correctly. Also even if I now change the content of these 2 files back to initial one, the code works.

@ChristophFroehlich I found that an error occurs specifically when creating an object of the class "GlowLed" in the file "diffbot_system.hpp". "GlowLed" class is created to communicate with hardware. Check "Edit_1" part of the question for more information.

The issue was not at all related to URDF.
The issue was with serial_comm.hpp. The issue with the order of initialization in the GlowLed constructor, specifically in the following line:
GlowLed():serial(io, port){

serial(io, port) tries to initialize the serial object with port and io, but at this point, port is still uninitialized.
The corrected code is:
-->serial_comm.hpp
#ifndef SERIAL_COMM_HPP
#define SERIAL_COMM_HPP

#include <iostream>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <thread>

class GlowLed
{
public:
    GlowLed() : port("/dev/ttyACM0"), baud_rate(9600), serial(io, port)
    {
        // Now, initialize the serial port options
        serial.set_option(boost::asio::serial_port_base::baud_rate(baud_rate));
    }

    void send_data(std::string data)
    {
        boost::asio::write(serial, boost::asio::buffer(data));
    }

private:
    std::string port;
    unsigned int baud_rate;
    boost::asio::io_service io;
    boost::asio::serial_port serial;
};

#endif


NOTE: Make sure the device(raspsberry pi pico in my case) is connected to pc/laptop. In my case, i am running ros2 on laptop and sending hardware command to pico via serial to glow led.
